# Flutter App is Incompatible With Nearly Everything?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I have built a Flutter app that works perfectly on my phone, but none of the others I have tried it on. [Here's the Git repo.](https://github.com/frc4976/frc2019-scouting-app)

My problem is that when I try to install from the APK I build, all the devices I'm trying to install it on say that the app is "incompatible." I have tried the app on the following devices:

- Samsung Galaxy J3
- Huawei P10
- Samsung Galaxy Core Prime
- LG something-or-other

It works on my Samsung Galaxy S8, and the Samsung Galaxy S7. Any and all help is greatly appreciated, as we are in a hurry.

Answer (score 4):

Flutter does not care about the model of device. Check if your project's minimum sdk version is higher than the Android version of the device that you try to install the app. It might be the cause of the problem.

Under your Flutter project, go to "android/app" folder. See the `minSdkVersion` field inside `build.gradle` file. Compare it with the Android version existing in your device.

Comment: I'm using minSdkVersion 16 but my app still doesn't run on a friend's Galaxy J3(Android 7)

Comment: I see same issue

Comment: same issue. Any solution?

Comment: I am getting the same issue minimum SDK version is 23. Tablet os sdk version is 29.

Comment: If people are still having this issue: use the command "flutter build apk", from terminal, inside the project directory and use the resulted: build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-release.apk to test on other devices.
You are most likely using the apk build for that device, meaning others are most likely to be incompatible, especially if they use other Android version/CPU/etc.

Answer (score 3):

[The solution that adi posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54818201/flutter-app-is-incompatible-with-nearly-everything/74212541#comment121640053_54822050) is still valid in 2022:

> If people are still having this issue: use the command "flutter build apk", from terminal, inside the project directory and use the resulted: build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-release.apk to test on other devices. You are most likely using the apk build for that device, meaning others are most likely to be incompatible, especially if they use other Android version/CPU/etc.

This can also be accomplished in Android Studio by going to **Build > Flutter > Build APK**

Works fine on a Samsung S22 Ultra with Flutter 3.3.5